# Using logback.xml in Apache Livy

Tags: apache-spark, logback, livy

I am trying to use `logback.xml` with **Apache Livy** ReST API and I'm having trouble getting it to work. I've tried submitting the `logback.xml` path as follows.

```
data = {
    "file" : "<PATH_TO_JAR_FILE>",
    "className" : "<CLASS_NAME>",
    "files": ["file:///path/to/log4j.properties", "file:///path/to/logback.xml"],
    "conf": {"driver-java-options":"-Dlogback.configurationFile=file:///path/to/logback.xml"}
}
```

However, I get the warning `Ignoring non-spark config property: driver-java-options=-Dlogback.configurationFile`. I can add the `logback.xml` file using `spark.driver.extraJavaOptions` instead of `driver-java-options`, but it doesn't make a difference since the JVM has already started. So my question is, How do I get Livy to use the `logback.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're trying to configure logging of Apache Livy server. But using its REST API (IIUC you are sending POST `/batches` or `/sessions`) you are submitting Spark job and feeding `logback.xml` to Spark Driver process, which is separate from Livy Server process.

What you need to do is to pass `-Dlogback.configurationFile=...` option to Livy Server process on its startup. Most probably (depending on your Livy version and environment) you should set `export LIVY_SERVER_JAVA_OPTS=-Dlogback.configurationFile=...` environment variable and start Livy with `$LIVY_HOME/bin/livy-server start`. Refer [the script](https://github.com/apache/incubator-livy/blob/master/bin/livy-server) on GitHub.